the output of Stim
As a beginner in Stim, it may be because I am not clear enough about the context, and I am not sure what content Stim can output? Perhaps it is because there are indeed a wide range of things it can do; The current understanding is the measurement result of a single measurement; Measurement results obtained from multiple samplings; Randomly generated circuit model; And for models with circuit errors?And now what I care most about is how Stim can be used for stabilizer code simulation

Have you read stim's getting started notebook?

I am honored to receive your answer.Yes, I have read the notebook and I will elaborate on my problem points in detail

I have seen on the StackExchange website about the reasons for multi measurement sampling, and I can understand this; But I still can't fully understand the role of the detector; I only have a vague understanding of its function


In addition, through reading the related article "Stim: a fast stabilizer circuit simulator", I learned that the sampling time is basically determined by the time of the first sampling. Therefore, my question is: if I input the stabilizer code I want to simulate into the circuit, of course, as a test, my stabilizer circuit is very small, and only one sampling is the measurement result of the stabilizer code? Is this measurement result the output of Stim?



By combining the decoding function of Pymatching, it is possible to calculate the logical error rate? Should this be considered as an output?



Through browsing various questions about Stim on the StackExchange website, I found that there are multiple forms of input for Stim, including file reading, direct circuit input, and parity check matrix reading. These methods can be converted into each other. Is my understanding correct?


Stim is a toolbox, so it doesn't have one single type of input or output. There are hundreds of methods listed in stim's API reference. Every one of them has inputs and outputs.
The most common forms of output would be getting a detector error model from calling stim.Circuit.detector_error_model() or getting a numpy array containing detection event samples by calling stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler().sample(...). But there's also classes for manipulating pauli strings, stabilizer tableaus, stabilizer flows, etc.
